# Optional and default values need to be initialized with default initializer

Tags: swift

Why can't I just bypass the initialization of `b` and `c` in the code below:

```
struct Token {
    var a: Int
    var b: Int = -1
    var c: Int?
}

let t1 = Token(a: 1, b: 2, c: 0) // works of course
let t2 = Token(a: 1) // doesn't work :-(
```

The only way I found is to add an init in the `struct` with the only mandatory parameter:

```
init(a: Int) { self.a = a }
```

But I find this language requirement very cumbersome and too verbose. Is there a way to achieve initialization of mandatory fields **only** without adding a constructor?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0018-flexible-memberwise-initialization.md (which has been deferred).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define an initializer with default values for some params

```
struct Token {
    var a: Int
    var b: Int
    var c: Int?

    init(a: Int, b: Int = -1, c: Int? = nil) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    }
}
```

Now you can create a Token in several ways

```
Token(a: 1) // (1, -1, nil)
Token(a: 1, b: 2) // (1, 2, nil)
Token(a: 1, c: 3) // (1, -1, 3)
Token(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3) // (1, 2, 3)
```

> Usually is a good practice writing the default value of a property on the same line where it is defined (as you did). I moved the default value of `b` from it's definition to the `init` just to make this example shorter.

Comment: I accepted this answer because to date, this is the only way to deal with this limitation. I read the proposal and I wonder why the complexity in the proposed design. A simpler and more appealing way should just be to adjust the default constructor to require only values that are required. Will wait for the additional syntactic sugar when it eventually comes. Thanks.